# Moving folders with the same name to new directory Linux, Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I have a folder with 100,000 sub-folders. 
Because of the size I cannot open the folder. 
Now I am looking for a shell script to help me move or split the folders.

Current = Folder Research : with 100,000 sub-folders. (Sorted A, B, C, D)

Needed = New folder All folders starting with name A-science. should be moved to a new
folder AScience.
All folders starting with B-Science.. should be move to a new folder BScience

I found this script below. But don't know how to make it work.

```
find /home/spenx/src -name "a1a2*txt" | xargs -n 1 dirname | xargs -I list mv list /home/spenx/dst/
find ~ -type d -name "*99966*" -print
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the command you supplied to see what it did. here's what each command does (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
| = pipes output of command to the left of pipe to the input of the command on the right
find /home/spenx/src -name "a1a2*txt" = finds all files within given directory that match between "" and pipes output 
xargs -n 1 dirname = takes in all the piped files outputted by the find command and gets the directory name of each file and pipes to output
xargs - I list mv list /home/spenx/dst = takes in all piped folders and and puts them into list variable, mv all items in list to the given folder
find ~ -type d -name "**" -print = runs a test for all files within given name to see if they exist and print any found out (this line is only a test command, it's not necessary for the actual move)


/home/spenx/src = folder to look in (absolute file path, or just folder name without '/')
/home/spenx/dst = folder to move all files to (absolute file path, or just folder name without '/')
"a1a2*txt" = files to look for (since you only care about folders, just use *.* to catch all files
"*99966* = files to test for but I'm not sure what you would put here
```

I took a look at the command and decided to modify it a little, but It still won't move each folder category (i.e. A-science, B-science) into a separate dirs, this will just get all folders in a given directory and move them to a given destination, or at least as far as I can tell.
You might want to try find all folders of each category ( A-Science) and moving them to a destination folder of `Ascience` one by one like so

`find /home/spenx/src -name "A-science/*.*" | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort -u | xargs - I list mv list /home/spenx/dst/Ascience`

`find /home/spenx/src -name "B-science/*.*" | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort -u | xargs - I list mv list /home/spenx/dst/Bscience`

Again, test the command out before using it on your actual files.

You might want to take look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928064/grep-filenames-matching-a-pattern-and-move-to-desired-folder?rq=1), specifically:

list.txt

```
1abc
2def
3xyz
```

script to run:

```
while read pattern; do
  mv "${pattern}"* ../folder_b/"$pattern"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Hi I forgot someting.. I dont know the name of the directory for hand.. The script need to do for example.. given that 5 diffrent directory has a name AS100, AS200, AS300 etc.. Then the search string should do "AS" create a director for all AS then move all directory like "AS*" to AS..

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was having and error here.. e_count=${$1}